# separate styles for check box CSS

Tags: html, css

**independent styles**

I have this problem, at the moment of applying the styles they are applied in all the checboxes that are found, I only think that the styles of each checkbox are applied independently and that only 1 can be selected

```css
  <style media="screen">
  /* Hide the checkbox */
  form p {
   position: relative; /* allows to position the checkbox */
  }

  [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
  [type="checkbox"]:checked {
   /* Hide the checkbox without
      making it hidden for the
      screen readers */
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   opacity: 0.01;
  }

  /* Preparing the label */
  [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
  [type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
   position: relative; /* allows to position the custom boxes */
   padding-left: 2.3em; /* space for upcoming boxes */
   font-size: 1.05em;
   line-height: 1.7;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  /* Box aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 1.4em;
 height: 1.4em;
 border: 1px solid #aaa;
 background: #FFF;
 border-radius: .2em;
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .1), 0 0 0 rgba(203, 34, 237, .2);
 transition: all .275s;
}

/* Check aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
 content: 'X';
 position: absolute;
 top: .38em;
 left: .18em;
 font-size: 1.6em;
 color: #CB22ED;
 line-height: 0;
 transition: all .2s; /* Little transition */
}

/* Unchecked aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scale(0) rotate(45deg);
}

/* Checked aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: scale(1) rotate(0);
}
  </style>
```

```html
<p>
 <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="test1" />
 <label for="test1" aria-describedby="label">YES</label>
</p>
<p>
 <input type="checkbox" id="test2" />
 <label for="test2" aria-describedby="label">NO</label>
</p>
```

As shown in the example, the styles appear for everyone but I only wish that each one had its content. I expect answers and thank you for your attention.

Comment: The validator flags your aria attributes as errors. Also, the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is targeting the HTML attribute `<input>` with the type of `type="checkbox"`. Therefore, any of those you have on the page will be targeted. However, you can override `input[type="checkbox"]` with an ID. To define an ID, simply put, on your HTML page. On each HTML tag like `<input>` or `<p>` or even `<textarea>` you can add an ID like this `<input id="thisIsWhateverYouWant" type="checkbox">` same goes for the others. To write it in CSS, inside the `<style>` tags you can write something like this `#thisIsWhateverYouWant {height: 100%; width: 100%}` Those styles will override what you have.

Here is a reference to what overrides what. [Check this out](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/id-selector-vs-class-selector-order-of-precedence)